# Multiple types in function

Tags: swift, function, class, types

I want to pass type `T` to the function (for example, it contains `RatingCell`), but I don’t understand how to make type `T` be defined exactly as `RatingCell`

```
func configureQuestionCell<T>(cellType: T, question: Question, answers: [String]?) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = self.blockContent.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ReusableCellID.pickerCell.rawValue) as! T
        //Value of type 'T' has no member ... 
        cell.delegate = self 
        cell.questionId = question.questionId
        cell.cellTitle.text = question.title
        cell.answerVariants = question.answerVariants 
        if answers != nil { 
            cell.userAnswers = answers!
        }
        return cell
    }
```

I add error in comment. I'm also sure `RatingCell` contains all this parameters

Comment: [Swift programming language book](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html), I think you will be helped by reading the chapters on Generics and Protocols

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to add a protocol

```
protocol Reusable {
    var delegate : ReusableDelegate { get set } // change the type to the real delegate type
}
```

and constrain the generic type to the protocol. You should constrain the generic type to `UITableViewCell` anyway

```
func configureQuestionCell<T>(cellType: T) where T : UITableViewCell & Reusable {
    let cell = self.blockContent.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ReusableCellID.ratingCell.rawValue) as! T
    cell.delegate = self
}
```

For multiple different delegate types use an associated type

```
protocol Reusable {
    associatedtype DelegateType
    var delegate : DelegateType { get set } 
}
```

And in the cell adopt the protocol and add

```
typealias DelegateType = < The actual delegate type of the cell >
```

Comment: How i can use it? Which delegate i need use?

Comment: The custom delegate type of the cell.

Comment: And what i need to do if a have 6-7 cell types? Can you show me any example?

Comment: I edit to for clarity. Currently still not decided how to specify T explicit type

Comment: It's the goal of generics that `T` is not explicit.